# Upload doesn't work right when the file is too big

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a PHP app where I can upload files. When I upload most files and do a `print_r($_FILES)`, I get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [import] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [excel_file] => COD MKTG 2.csv
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [excel_file] => application/vnd.ms-excel
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [excel_file] => /tmp/phpy8mEKn
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [excel_file] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [excel_file] => 1584286
                )

        )

)
```

I have another CSV file that's more like 13 megabytes, and when I try to upload that, I get this:

```
Array
(
    [import] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [excel_file] => COD MKTG.csv
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [excel_file] => 
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [excel_file] => 
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [excel_file] => 1
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [excel_file] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

I don't get any error saying the file's too big. I just get a malformed `$_FILES`. I have `post_max_size` in php.ini set to 100MB. Why is this happening?

Comment: Double check that it's the php.ini file that PHP is actually using, and not a copy

Comment: Good suggestion - that's burned me before. In this case, it's the same, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per the PHP docs, error code 1 is [UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php): "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"

You need to make sure all the following variables are properly set:

[upload_max_filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) - max size of any individual file in an upload
[max_file_uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads) - total number of files allowed to be uploaded
[post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) - sum total of all data being POSTed (form data + files)
[memory_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) - must be > post_max_size, to allow space for PHP + script overhead

And on top of that, there's the web server limits as well. Apache's got [LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) which would apply long before PHP ever enters the picture.

Comment: It turned out to be `upload_max_filesize`. I could tell because the error code was "1": http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Yep. that was in your original post.

Answer (score 1):

change the memory limit aswell
memory_limit = 8M ;

to perhaps 20?

and perhaps execution time

max_execution_time

edit:

make sure its not execution time look it up...

if you got a really slow internet connection it could be

max_input_time

it has to be one of these or there's something wrong with your script
or your not setting the settings correctly

memory_limit

max_execution_time

max_input_time

Comment: No, my memory_limit was 128M and I still get the same results at 256. My script's not timing out, either.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try setting these values in a .htaccess file within your root directory

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
php_value post_max_size 128M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, PHP has problems with big files when it comes to filesystem functions. 32-bit compiled PHP has 2147483647 as PHP_INT_MAX, which means files bigger than ~2G won't open, seek, etc. This number is bigger in 64-bit compiled PHP [around 4+ trillion bytes - 8 byte signed integer that is].

At this very moment, I am trying to solve this problem [I am trying to integrate JumpLoader to my CMS project. It is done, except the part related to this 2G capsize problem - can't work on files bigger than 2G.], so once I get a solution on this one, will share it.

Good luck for now.