# Too big POST data. Reduce the data or increase the "post_max_size"

Tags: php, mysql, adminer

I'm trying to upload a gzipped Mysql backup (71,2mb) through Adminer and it throws me this error:

> Too big POST data. Reduce the data or increase the "post_max_size" configuration directive.

Even though my post_max_size and other php.ini settings is like this:

```
post_max_size = 1024M
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
```

Why do i keep getting this error?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044201/upload-doesnt-work-right-when-the-file-is-too-big?rq=1

Comment: have you also changed the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't only check values in `php.ini`, as they can be overwritten by a `.htaccess` file or in PHP code. Run a `phpinfo()` and compare values in left & right column. The values in the right column are those actually in use.

Also take the notes from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) into account:

> Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file
>   upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than
>   upload_max_filesize. If memory limit is enabled by your configure
>   script, memory_limit also affects file uploading. Generally speaking,
>   memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size.

So, you might also need to change `memory_limit`:

```
memory_limit > post_max_size > upload_max_filesize
```

Comment: Don't forget to restart your servers if you are working locally.. ;)

Comment: @marcelosarquis sounds like you've found out the hard way :D