# PHP memory_limit and $_FILES size

Tags: php, .htaccess, config, memory-limit

When I try to upload a file, I check the file size like this:

```
if($_FILES['attachment_file']['size'] > (1024 * 1024 * 20)) // 20 MB
{
echo 'The file is too big !'; exit();
}
```

And in my htaccess file I have:

```
php_value memory_limit 21M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value upload_max_filesize 21M
php_value post_max_size 21M
```

So, I check using php if the file has more than 20 MB, then stop the script. But the error "The file is too big !" is not showing...

In the php errors log I get the error "Allowed memory size of 22020096 bytes exhausted".

If I change `(1024 * 1024 * 20)` to `(1024 * 1024 * 10)`, it's working as expected. The php catch the error and show me the message: "The file is too big !".

Where is the problem ? Why is not working with 20 MB ?

PS: I check the phpinfo to see if the config from htaccess is taken and it's ok.

Comment: are you on local or on a server? maybe you are not allowed to set memory_limit  to >20M?

Comment: Yes, I'm on localhsot, but I already said that the phpinfo sais that the config from htaccess is taken. So I'm allowed....

Comment: It sounds like there might be more going on than the posted snippet. I have two questions: what's on the line that causes the out of memory error and how big is the file you're testing with? Also, does it work with a very small file?

Comment: The file has 16 Mb and the error from logs are:: 
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 66000 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\require\ADMIN_files.php on line 110
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\index.php:0
PHP   2. require_once() C:\wamp\www\index.php:3
PHP   3. require_once() C:\wamp\www\require\REQ_require.php:39
PHP   4. imagecreatefromjpeg() C:\wamp\www\require\ADMIN_files.php:110

Comment: Oooo... The file has only 16Mb.... then that means that the php condition it's ok. Then why the imagecreatefromjpeg return this error ? memory_limit is 128 Mn...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `imagecreatefromjpeg()`, I suspect it needs to allocate enough memory to store the raw pixel data from the source image. That is, loading a 10x10 image will require 10*10*3 = 300 bytes of storage or more just for the pixel data. Given the JPEG size, I suspect you have a very large image. The size of that pixel data plus any PHP overhead could exceed your memory limits, especially if you are doing any sort of manipulation beyond reading and saving.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing your memory limit in .htaccess above 21MB to allow for applications runtime memory, or by using this in PHP:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```

Comment: memory_limit increased to 128M. The error 'The file is too big !' still not showing :( The server seems to stop and the error log sais: "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted". It's true that the file that I want to upload is very very big, but the php shouldn't show me the error "The files is too big" ? I don't get it...

Comment: Your file size is probably ok, it's just the code which you execute after is reaching the memory limit. Check to see if there are any optimisations you can make or possible loops which run forever. If you're manipulating a large file in memory then the PHP process can easily use 128M memory.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to make sure all the following variables are properly set:**

```
upload_max_filesize - max size of any individual file in an upload
max_file_uploads - total number of files allowed to be uploaded
post_max_size - sum total of all data being POSTed (form data + files)
memory_limit - must be > post_max_size, to allow space for PHP + script overhead
```

@ref: [Upload doesn't work right when the file is too big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044201/upload-doesnt-work-right-when-the-file-is-too-big)

and get rid of this condition

```
if($_FILES['attachment_file']['size'] > (1024 * 1024 * 20)) // 20 MB
{
echo 'The file is too big !'; exit();
}
```